# CMYK profiles issue

Tags: cmyk, color-profile, grayscale

When I’m working on a CMYK file with a *SWOP Coated* profile in Photoshop, I can convert my QR code color to true black (K=100%) by opening a new work space with the same dimensions but changing the color mode to grayscale, then I just select the QR code and drag it – holding shift – to the grayscale work space then drag it back to the original CMYK file and it’s true black now.

My question is: I have some CMYK work with the FOGRA39 profile and I tried to do my trick to convert the QR code’s color to true black but it doesn’t work with the FOGRA39 color profile.

### I would like to know:

1. What is the difference between the two color profiles, SWOP Coated and FOGRA39, regarding the problem I mentioned above.
2. What color profile should I use when working on CMYK files?
   Note: I’m working at a commercial printing company.
3. Should I use the same color profile for Illustrator as Photoshop? For example: When I want to add some touches using Photoshop to a file made in Illustrator and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you are working at a printing company you should already have some guidelines on what profiles you should be using. Standardization is everything is this industry.

That being said here's my breakdown for your questions.

### 1. SWOP vs FOGRA

They are different standards that have been created to work with the most printing presses. They are developed by testing a large number of presses using a range of paper types and produced a set of datasets.

The main difference is that `SWOP` is used for printing in the US and `FOGRA` is used for UK/EU printers. That being said this is just how each profile is *GENERALLY* used, there can certainty be printers in the EU using the `SWOP` standard.

### 2. The best color profile I should use when working on CMYK files

If you are being supplied images or artwork the client **SHOULD** always specify what color space they need. If they don't that's a whole other talk about project management.

Most will suggest `ISO Coated v2` or Coated `FOGRA39`. Others will have different international standards that they conform to and have profiles they can send you. A few will still just say `CMYK` and not know enough about color management to be more specific. If that is the case then `ISO Coated v2`/`Coated FOGRA39` would still be the safest choice.

### 3. Should I use the same color profile for Illustrator as Photoshop

**YES YES YES YES**. You should **ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS** work in the same color profile from software to software. I can not stress this enough.

---

Bonus:
I'm not really sure why you are going through this trouble for a QR code, your rip software (software used to send files to the printing press) should be set to the correct profile for printing.

As long as you aren't trying to send `RGB` art to the press the software should strip any profiles associated with the art and use the correct ones for the press.

Additionally, what file format is the QR code? If it's anything remotely vector editable you can just manually select the art and change its color. If it isn't you can vectorize it very easily.

Comment: Good answer. Just to complicate it a little more: Why even work in CMYK in PS in the first place? I believe the simplest workflow would be to EDIT images in PS as RGB or grayscale, then PLACE them in an InDesign/Illustrator document and finally CONVERT to the correct CMYK profile when exporting a pdf. For the CMYK color profile to work properly you must let it decide the CMYK values. If you edit the images after converting to CMYK they might not comply to the profile (even though it seems so). Read about it here: https://indesignsecrets.com/import-rgb-images-indesign-convert-cmyk-export.php

Comment: Very good point.  I overlooked the workflow aspect, I was more concerned that he/she isn't mixing RGB in their CMYK.

Comment: First, thank you guys for your replies, really appreciate them :)

Comment: Well, about the company I'm working at, it's kind of a small workshop, we don't have standard color profile ( i don't know how to find the best color profile for our press machine ) .. Plus, i have never seen a customer saying anything about the color profile he would like to use , they just say CMYK . anyway, 80% of my work is to finalize the work sent to us by the mail and to impose (montax) it, also to fix some mistakes if it's possible (like: Converting all texts to 100% black and convert the QR as well which is a jpg as usual)

Comment: That's why I need to convert the QR by this tricky way, by the way , i think i found how to convert the QR by dragging it from FOGRA profile to Gayscale workspace but only i have to go to Edit> assign profile> then choose the middle choice - i don't remember it now - after i drag it back to the CMYK FOGRA i can go to EDIT> assign profile> then choose the third choice again ... Well, i mentioned this Bcos i dont understand it, Maybe someone can explain

Comment: Anyway, @Ovaryraptor you said something about victorising the QR very easily , can you please tell me how?

Comment: About the differences between SWOP and FOGRA , I'm someone -he not she :) - who lives in Egypt so i don't know which one should i use .. If this can help, the press machine's type is HEIDELBERG... I have another thing to ask about, what should I just work using the same profile sent to me by customer ? Or i should find my machine's best profile ?

Comment: Sorry for all these questions - especially I'm typing in a broken English - but can someone tell me what's rip software? Of course we don't have one , we even impose the work manually ... I know I'm a beginner and a looser, but I'm trying hard to gain more experience .. Thank you all:)